# Fastest (and safest) way to create 1300 workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with some data, which I want to filter and then save filtered data to new workbook. Function looks like this:

```
Sub bleh()
  For Each i In Number
       ~~ filter, copy, paste, save ~~
  Next i 
End Sub
```

Apart from optimizing code, is it faster and safer to

1. save each worksheet as new workbook in each iteration
2. save each worksheet in current workbook and cut whole workbook
   into separate workbooks at the end?

Or maybe something else?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Safety wise no way I'd create 1300 worksheets before saving. Also, I'd farm the individual operations to a separate sub so that the variables can be garbage collected. E.g. Sub Loop() For i = 1 to 1300 Call DoSave(workbook i) Next i End Sub.

Comment: quote: *...cut whole workbook into separate workbooks at the end...* which would be the same like *...save each worksheet as new workbook...* just without the save between... just by logic, you answered already your own question ;)

Comment: But to do it faster than working with the sheets and splitting and whatever: push values in a variable -> calculate outcome as one long string -> write to textfile (save as csv) ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel I clearly emphasized two factors - speed and safety.

Comment: Perhaps if the data is centralized you can create one template (You'd copy  it 1300 times, and rename each) that just uses SQL to select the data that's needed. You could name each workbook with a specific name, that translates to what the selection criteria would be for the SQL statement.

Answer (score 5):

1,300 files? Forget VBA, forget even Excel interop.

I'd go with some C# or VB.NET, and use OpenXML to *work with the file's structure*, generate the 1,300 OpenXML documents (i.e. workbooks) in-memory asynchronously (hopefully there's not hundreds of thousands of rows of data per sheet), and then once you have everything you need to know, iterate all these workbook objects and save them to disk sequentially (perhaps showing a progress bar or something). Making the I/O asynchronous isn't going to help anything anyway.

Each file write would be wrapped inside a `try/catch` block and any exception thrown in the process would be handled by logging enough information to identify the failing sheets later (could be output to a locked textbox under that progress bar), and then moving on to try with the next one.

---

Doing this in VBA will run forever: give each workbook 4 seconds to be created, saved and closed - your macro will run for at least 5,200 seconds, which is pretty much an hour and a half.

Comment: My time is limited to time spent doing the work manually. Is it far from VBA to VB.NET?